# Plugin getting Cannot modify header information errors

Tags: plugins, admin, errors, options

I am trying to build my first plugin but am receiving the following error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at `/wp-admin/includes/template.php:1642`) in `/wp-includes/pluggable.php` on line 876

But here's the thing: template.php isn't 1600 lines long and pluggable doesn't have any whitespace at that point.

My plugin code is as follows:

```
<?php  
/* 
Plugin Name: Test 
Plugin URI: http://www.Test.com
Description: Test
Author: Test
Version: 1.0 
Author URI: http://www.Test.com
*/  

function Test_admin() {  
    include('admin.php');  
}
function Test_admin_actions() { 
    $icon_url = "";
    add_menu_page( "Test", "Test", "switch_themes", "Test", "Test_admin", $icon_url, 58 );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'Test_admin_actions');
?>
```

The admin.php file is currently empty.

The plugin adds a Test menu option in the admin page just before the Appearance option. When you click on it, you should theoretically get a white page but instead, you get the error.

So I'm pretty dumbfounded by this. I've disabled, deleted, and reinstalled my plugin to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: So the error disappears after the plugin is deactivates? It is definitely a problem with *this* plugin?

Comment: Yes. This error happens uniquely when clicking the Test menu option that the plugin adds.

Comment: It appears that something is trying to use the `wp_redirect()` function after the admin header has been printed

Comment: What would that be? My plugin doesn't do anything. My entire code is what is posted.

Comment: Have you tried changing the names of your functions? Possible conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll guess your include is failing. If it's in the same directory as your main plugin file, try:

```
include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/admin.php' );
```

Comment: Yes, this could be the reason +1

Comment: That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a space after the closing `?>` tag. The WordPress Codex [recommends](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#Remove_Trailing_Spaces) that you drop the closing tag completely.

Comment: Negative. No spaces after the closing tag. Even with the closing tag removed, the error persists.

Comment: It's a good suggestion all the same, it's good practice to leave out the closing tag to avoid whitespace and headers sent errors more easily.